# Can't Import Automation Account Storage Module using Bicep

Tags: module, azure-automation, azure-bicep

Hi im trying to import an automaiton account module to an Automatino account that i have Using Bicep

the Module

- Az.Storage
- version : 2.0.0

Following the Documentation im using this code :

```
 resource znssPSModulesAzStorageName 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules@2020-01-13-preview' = {
   name: psModules.azStorage.name
   location: location
   parent: znssAutomationAccountName
   tags:{}
   properties: {
     contentLink:{
       uri: 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/packages/Az.Storage/2.0.0'
          
     }
   }
 }
```

but im getting this error :

> Error importing the module Az.Storage. Import failed with the
> following error:
> Orchestrator.Shared.AsyncModuleImport.ModuleImportException: No
> content was read from the supplied ContentLink.
> [ContentLink.Uri=https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/packages/Az.Storage/2.0.0]
> at
> Orchestrator.Activities.GetModuleContentActivity.ExecuteInternal(CodeActivityContext
> context, String contentUri, String contentHashAlgorithm, String
> contentHashValue, String contentVersion, String moduleName,
> ModuleLanguage moduleLanguage) at
> Orchestrator.Activities.GetModuleContentActivity.Execute(CodeActivityContext
> context) at
> System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance
> instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
> at
> System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor
> executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

is there a problem with the link in powershell Gallery
i searched in the internet and couldn't find anything useful

hope someone can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Problem is in the uri instead of :

uri: 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/**packages**/Az.Storage/2.0.0

use : package singular wihout the s

uri: 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/**package**/Az.Storage/2.0.0

it should work :

```
resource znssPSModulesAzStorageName 'Microsoft.Automation/automationAccounts/modules@2020-01-13-preview' = {
   name: psModules.azStorage.name
   location: location
   parent: znssAutomationAccountName
   tags:{}
   properties: {
     contentLink:{
       uri: 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/Az.Storage/2.0.0'
          
     }
   }
 }
```